# Request spec in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am doing a rather trivial request spec but cannot make it pass. Any hint would be much appreciated :).

```
CheckoutController:

def create_membership
  ...
  if @membership.save
    redirect_to checkout_payment_path(id: @membership.id)
  ...
end

def payment
  @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
  @transaction = Transaction.new
  @transaction.amount = @membership.product.price
  ... 
end

Routes:
  namespace :checkout do
    get 'payment'
  end

RSpec:
  let(:member) { create(:member) }
  let(:membership) { create(:membership, member: member) }
  let(:transaction) { create(:transaction, membership: membership) }

  describe "GET 'payment'" do
    it "return transaction" do
      Membership.any_instance.stub(:find).and_return(membership)
      get :payment, id: membership.id 
      assigns(:transaction).should be_a_new(Transaction)
      ...
    end
  end
```

I have setup Factories so that for each created membership, an associated product is created hence `@membership.product.price` is valid.

The rspec failed at this line `get :payment, id: membership.id`. Error says `undefined method 'price' for nil:NilClass`. I am sure I have setup instance variable before test correctly. Did I make any small mistake here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the .any_instance from your stub:

```
Membership.stub(:find).and_return(membership)
```

The payment method is doing a find on the Membership class, not an instance of Membership.